# Plotly file permission error in production

Tags: python, flask, plotly, gunicorn, plotly-dash

I recently moved a plotly chart in flask environment to production using `gunicorn`.

For some reason I get the following error:

```
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)                 
  File "/var/www/html/dir/flask-gentelella/app/home/routes.py", line 27, i
n <module>                                                                      
    plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='users', api_key='abc4')                                                                   
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/tools.py", l
ine 130, in set_credentials_file                                                
    raise exceptions.PlotlyError("You don't have proper file permissions "      
plotly.exceptions.PlotlyError: You don't have proper file permissions to run this function.
```

I'm not able to rectify it since this is does not happen in virtual environment

Please guide

Answer (score 0):

The function `set_credentials_file` tries to write the credentials to the following file: `~/.plotly_credentials`.

Probability the permissions for the home folder (`~`) are not correct and the python process can’t write in this location.

Have a look at the permission of the home folder of the user the process runs as.

Comment: but if it's a permission error, it shouldn't work when I run plotly in virtual env. It is specifically not working with gunicorn or any production server

Comment: As what user are you running flask in the venv and which user is running the Gunicorn process?

Comment: as 'ec2-user' for both process, however fixed using `plotly_signin()` for now